# Usage of prepositions with "to smb's advantage", "for smb's benefit"

Tags: prepositions

The meaning differences of these two phrases are slim. How can using the prepositions "to" and "for" be explained here from a grammatical point of view? Why is there such a difference whereas it's not about a directional notice, even abstract (with "to")?

Comment: If you are asking "why are English prepositions the way that they are?" then I'm not sure there is an answer.  The choice often seems random.

Comment: @stangdon I think I have been arriving at this inference but I have not finished this arriving and I'm not sure I ever shall. Because there must be logic in their usage which is to be found in the older times when it settled down/became idiomatic.

Comment: As to rangomizing, which would be expedient in the meaning "It's for you to choose" (and maybe each usage would be in certain cases?): "It's at your choice", "It's for your choice", "It's to your choice", "It's of your choice"?